# Uncertainty principle in probability theory

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, signal-processing, fourier-transform

In probability theory, there is the covariance inequality

$$\operatorname{Var}(Y) \geq \frac{\operatorname{Cov}(Y,X)^{2}}{\operatorname {Var} (X)}.$$

In signal processing, there is a similar inequality, called Heisenberg's uncertainty principle or Gabor limit:

$$\Delta_t\Delta_{\omega} \geq \frac{1}{2}$$

where $\Delta_t$, $\Delta_{\omega}$ is the standard deviation of the time domain and frequency domain of a signal respectively. More concretely,

$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{E}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(t-t_c)^2|x(t)|^2 dt} \sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi E}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\omega - \omega_c\right)^2|X(i\omega)|^2d\omega} \geq \frac{1}{2}.$$

Some more information can be found [here](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Eee120/fa04/Fall04/Lectures/uncertaintyprinciple.pdf).

Now, I am wondering whether the covariance inequality can be written as in equation 2 when we assume a regular random variable and not a signal (same random variable, but one Fourier transformed and one in the time domain). I am looking for more of a probabilistic interpretation.

Comment: Not a physicist -- but I understand the first equation is equivalent to Cauchy-Schwarz; intuitively, I see a similar form in the inequalities below. A quick search for connections between Heisenberg's uncertainty principle and Cauchy-Schwarz yields (this proof)[http://www.phys.ufl.edu/courses/phy4604/fall18/uncertaintyproof.pdf], which uses Cauchy-Schwarz for functions to prove the Heisenberg uncertainty principle in the $\Delta_t \Delta_w$ form you have above up to a constant. However, I'm not familiar enough with the material to comment further.

Comment: I don't think you can get to anything like the uncertainty principle that way.  Equation 2 is written in terms of a complementary pair (location, frequency), so it can be applied to quantum uncertainty, but equation 1 is more general -- there's no reason $X$ and $Y$ should be based on the same phenomenon. $X$ could be the readout on Dr Bell's Geiger counter and $Y$ the number of pairs of clean underpants that Dr Bohr currenty has.